# Laurent expansion of $f (z) = \frac1{z(z − 1)(z − 2)},$ (in powers of $z$) for $0 < |z| < 1,$ $1 < |z| < 2,$ and $|z| > 2.$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent expansion of $$f (z) = \frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}$$
(in powers of $z$) for

a. $0 < |z| < 1$

b. $1 < |z| < 2$

c. $|z| > 2$

Comment: First, do a partial fraction decomposition. Then expanding each summand is easy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to do, here, is what is known as a partial fraction decomposition. Write $$\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}=\frac{A}{z}+\frac{B}{z-1}+\frac{C}{z-2},$$ and solve for $A,B,C.$

Note that for $z\neq0,2,$ we can write $$\frac1{z-2}=-\frac1{2-z}=-\frac12\cdot\cfrac1{1-\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}$$ and $$\frac1{z-2}=\frac1{z}\cdot\cfrac1{1-\left(\frac{2}{z}\right)}.$$

Now, one of these can be expanded as a multiple of a geometric series in the disk $|z|<2,$ and the other can be expanded as a multiple of a geometric series in the annulus $|z|>2$. That is, we will use the fact that $$\frac1{1-w}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty w^k$$ whenever $|w|<1$. You should figure out which region works for which rewritten version, and find the respective expansions in both cases.

Likewise, we can rewrite $\frac1{z-1}$ in two similar forms, one of which is expandable in $|z|<1$ and one of which is expandable in $|z|>1.$

Using the partial fraction decomposition with the expansions you found above will give you three different Laurent expansions of $f(z),$ one for each of the regions $0<|z|<1,$ $1<|z|<2,$ and $|z|>2$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start!  My textbook has very few numerical examples, can you show all the work from beginning to end for at least 1 of the regions?

Comment: I will leave it to you to determine which region is correct in each instance, but I will show you how to expand one of the expressions I mentioned above. For appropriate $z,$ we have $$\begin{align}\frac1{z-2} &= \frac1z\cdot\cfrac1{1-\left(\frac2z\right)}\\ &= \frac1z\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac2z\right)^k\\ &= \frac1z\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k}{z^k}\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k}{z^{k+1}}\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^{k-1}}{z^k}\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{k-1}z^{-k}\\ &= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}2^{-k-1}z^k.\end{align}$$ Were you able to work out the partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: yes, thanks again you've been a great help

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to "accept" my answer by clicking the little check mark.

Comment: @CameronBuie, can you show me how to do it in the region $0 < |z|<1$? This is the only type of region I don't know how to do these for. I'm teaching myself, and I can't find any examples that don't involve $0< |z+\text{something}|< 1$.

Comment: @Jessy: Show you how to do *what* in the region $0<|z|<1$?

Comment: @JessyCat: I'm happy to help you, but I need to know what you want me to help you do.

Comment: @CameronBuie, never mind. Figured it out! :)