# find the laurent expansion valid for:

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am very confused! I am trying to Expand a given function in a Laurent series valid for different values of z for a complex variables class. I tried going to my professor for help and she was able to help for part b and gave me some good hints for c and d, however I am still struggling to figure this out.

The questions states:

> expand $f(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)(2-z)}$ in a Laurent series valid for:
>
> - a) $\quad|z|<1$
> - b) $\quad1<|z|<2$
> - c) $\quad|z|>2$
> - d) $\quad|z-1|>1$
> - e) $\quad0<|z-2|<1$

[Find the Laurent expansion of f (z) = 1/( z(z − 1)(z − 2)), (in powers of z) for: a. 0 < |z| < 1 b. 1 < |z| < 2 c. |z| > 2.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537298/find-the-laurent-expansion-of-f-z-1-zz-%E2%88%92-1z-%E2%88%92-2-in-powers-of-z-for)
I found this example helpful because it attempts to solve for part b of this user's question (I think) using the same process that I am trying, however I'm confused why you just consider one part of the partial fraction as opposed to both.

For part b) I was told to do it for both parts of the partial fraction and then add the resulting Laurent series together.
What I came up with was the sum of $\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^n$ for $n=[0,\infty]$ + the sum of $\frac{1}{z^n}$ for $n=[1,\infty]$. 
So when I try and do this for part A and C (i.e. only considering one half of the partial fraction) I get confused because I'm getting an incorrect answer.

If someone could work one of these through and explain what they are doing I would really appreciate it!

The answers provided by the back of the book are:

> - a) $$-\frac{z}{2}-\frac{3z^2}{4}-\frac{7z^3}{8}-\frac{15z^4}{16}$$
> - b) $$\cdots+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z}+1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{4}+\frac{z^3}{8}+\cdots$$
> - c) $$-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{z^2}-\frac{7}{z^3}-\frac{15}{z^4}-\cdots$$

(this one is especially confusing to me because it seems like its missing the first order z term)

> - d) $$-(z-1)^{-1} - 2(z-1)^{-2} - 2(z-1)^{-3} - \ldots$$
> - e) $$1-2(z-2)^{-1}-(z-2)^{-1}-(z-2)+(z-2)^2-(z-2)^3+(z-2)^4-\ldots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is basically what [Cameron](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28900/cameron-buie) already mentioned in his [reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537298/find-the-laurent-expansion-of-f-z-1-zz-%E2%88%92-1z-%E2%88%92-2-in-powers-of-z-for). First, use partial fractions to expand $f(z)$

$$
f(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)(2 - z)} = z\bigg(\frac{a}{z - 1} + \frac{b}{2 - z}\bigg) =
z\bigg(\frac{z(b - a) + (2a - b)}{(z-1)(2 - z)}\bigg) ,
$$

which implies $a=b=1$,

$$
f(z) = \frac{z}{z - 1} + \frac{z}{2 - z}
$$

Before we go to your questions remember that if $|x|<1$ then

$$
\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^k
$$

- $|z| < 1$

  In this region $|z/2| = |z|/2 < 1/2 < 1$, therefore

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(z) &=& -z\frac{1}{1 - z} + \frac{z}{2}\frac{1}{1 - z/2}\\
&=& -z\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} z^k + \frac{z}{2} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{2^{k + 1}} - 1\right)z^{k+1} 
\end{eqnarray*}

- $1< |z| < 2$

  In this case note that $|1/z| < 1$, and $|z/2| < 1$, then

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(z) &=& \frac{1}{1 - 1/z} + \frac{z}{2}\frac{1}{1 - z/2}\\
&=& \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^k} + \frac{z}{2} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{z^{k}} +  \frac{1}{2^{k + 1}}z^{k+1} \bigg)
\end{eqnarray*}

- $|z| > 2$

  For this region $|1/z| < 1/2 < 1$ and $|2/z| < 1$ so that

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(z) &=& \frac{1}{1 - 1/z} - \frac{1}{1 - 2/z}\\
&=& \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^k} - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{z}\right)^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( 1 - 2^{k}\right)\frac{1}{z^k} 
\end{eqnarray*}

- $|z - 1| > 1$

  Note that $1 / |z - 1| < 1$

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(z) &=& \frac{(z-1)+1}{z - 1} + \frac{(z-1)+1}{1 - (z - 1)} =1+ \frac{1}{z - 1} - \frac{(z-1)+1}{z-1}\frac{1}{1 - 1/(z - 1)}\\
&=&1+ \frac{1}{z - 1} -\frac{1}{1 - 1/(z - 1)} -\frac{1}{z - 1}\frac{1}{1 - 1/(z - 1)}\\
&=& 1+\frac{1}{z - 1} -\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{z - 1}\right)^k -\frac{1}{z - 1} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{z - 1}\right)^k = \frac{1}{z - 1} - 2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z - 1)^k}
\end{eqnarray*}